# django, logged in via rest api, doesn't show in browser

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am working on openedx and i'm creating a user_login api, that will login the user coming from a particular site.
I'm able to log in the user via 
`login(request,user)` function and it's showing an output :

```
 2016-06-30 01:57:23,361 INFO 5426 [audit] models.py:1805 - Login
 success - chogath (chogath@leauge.com)
```

But when I login to the said login page from browser,it still shows the user not logged in, I was expecting to be redirected to the dashboard.

Am I missing something here? Any help would be appreciated, thanks .

Comment: Does the auth cookie gets set on the correct domain?

Answer (score 0):

Are you issuing a request explicitly after the `login` function? `login` will not create a response for you automatically, you have to do something like [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login). Use `return redirect(...)` or `return render(...)`.